# javascript button doesn't wait for to be clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a simple random color generator application. The barrier is that the button created through javascript is clicked automatically even before any click event on it. I am new to javascript
Here is my whole code. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function btn(){
            var cgen = document.createElement('button');
            cgen.innerHTML = 'Generate';
            document.body.appendChild(cgen);
            cgen.style.width = '100%';
            cgen.style.fontSize = '20px';
            cgen.style.border = '2px solid red';
            cgen.onclick = paintDivs();
            // cgen.setAttribute("onclick", paintDivs());
        }
        function genColor(){
            var randomColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
            return randomColor;
        }
        function paintDivs(){
            for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
                var fColor = genColor();
                var bColor = genColor();
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerHTML = 'Text &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + fColor + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Back &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + bColor; 
                div.style.color = fColor;
                div.style.background = bColor;
                div.style.width = '24%';
                div.style.float = 'left';
                div.style.margin = '5px';
                div.style.height = '60px';
                div.style.fontSize = '18px';
                div.style.lineHeight = '60px';
                div.style.textAlign = 'center';
                div.style.borderRadius = '20px';
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="btn();" style="background-color: gray;">
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cgen.onclick = paintDivs();
```

That calls `paintDivs()` immediately and sets `cgen.onclick` to its return value.  What you want is this:

```
cgen.onclick = paintDivs;
```

Comment: @Felix-Robinchik please always accept an answer if that is what you are looking for thank you

Comment: @Mark Reed Sorry brother. I was out. Why not. I was accepting your answer at that moment but I was unable to accept for 11 mins.

Comment: That wasn't me prodding you, @Felix-Robinchik, but thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

try below code . 
have change cgen.onclick = paintDivs(); to cgen.onclick = paintDivs;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btn(){
        var cgen = document.createElement('button');
        cgen.innerHTML = 'Generate';
        document.body.appendChild(cgen);
        cgen.style.width = '100%';
        cgen.style.fontSize = '20px';
        cgen.style.border = '2px solid red';
        cgen.onclick = paintDivs;
        // cgen.setAttribute("onclick", paintDivs());
    }
    function genColor(){
        var randomColor = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        return randomColor;
    }
    function paintDivs(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            var fColor = genColor();
            var bColor = genColor();
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = 'Text &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + fColor + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Back &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + bColor; 
            div.style.color = fColor;
            div.style.background = bColor;
            div.style.width = '24%';
            div.style.float = 'left';
            div.style.margin = '5px';
            div.style.height = '60px';
            div.style.fontSize = '18px';
            div.style.lineHeight = '60px';
            div.style.textAlign = 'center';
            div.style.borderRadius = '20px';
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="btn();" style="background-color: gray;">
</body>
</html>
</html>
```